# SQLiteException on first database call after upgrade

Tags: android, android-sqlite

Background: Basically we do a new release of our app every month with an updated database (which is pre-populated). To ensure that the user has the latest data, we use 'setForcedUpgrade()' in the constructor.

Problem: Recently (mostly Android 9 release, also found on 8.1 a few times) we have been getting crash reports on the Google Play console:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: 
  at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done (AsyncTask.java:366)
  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.finishCompletion (FutureTask.java:383)
  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException (FutureTask.java:252)
  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run (FutureTask.java:271)
  at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run (AsyncTask.java:257)
  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker (ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1167)
  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run (ThreadPoolExecutor.java:641)
  at java.lang.Thread.run (Thread.java:784)
Caused by: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: 
  at com.readystatesoftware.sqliteasset.SQLiteAssetHelper.getReadableDatabase (SQLiteAssetHelper.java:266)
  at ...
```

I went to go check out SQLiteAssetHelper.java:266 and found:

```
if (db.getVersion() != mNewVersion) {
                throw new SQLiteException("Can't upgrade read-only database from version " +
                        db.getVersion() + " to " + mNewVersion + ": " + path);
}
```

So, I'm suspecting that maybe the database upgrade has NOT completed yet by the time we are trying to access the database again. But, I have no idea how to fix this. My first thought was to 'listen' for when the upgrade completes before letting the user continue with the app, but I couldn't really find a way to do that.

Also note, that the database is already on version 23, so its not something we have changed recently (the bug is new).

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Simplified version of helper:

```
public class MyDBHelper extends SQLiteAssetHelper {

/** The database version. */
private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 24;

/** The name of the database. */
private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "myDB.db";

public MyDBHelper(Context context) {
    super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
    setForcedUpgrade();
}

public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
   //Empty
}
}
```